# SQL Functions using MIN and MAX together

Tags: sql

I am trying to get 2 pieces of information from a database by using the MIN and MAX function.
This is my statement:

```
Select MIN(SAL) AND MAX(SAL) From EMP;
```

I just cannot get the result, I get an error saying From keyword not found where expected.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use a comma instead of AND:

```
Select MIN(SAL), MAX(SAL) From EMP
```

You might also want to consider giving your columns aliases:

```
SELECT
   MIN(SAL) AS min_sal,
   MAX(SAL) AS max_sal
FROM EMP
```

Comment: Just to note, you don't have to use AS, but it will make it does make things cleaner.