# how do i only show the min and max values in sql? my code is showing all the values

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi so i am making a database and want to return only the minimum value and maximum value with  other information in other columns so i want to display like the shopID and the brands and brand name

```
SELECT Shop.ShopID, 
       Brand.BrandID, 
       Brand.Brand_name, 
       price
FROM Brand 
INNER JOIN Shop ON Brand.BrandID = Shop.BrandID
WHERE Brand.BrandID = 1
ORDER BY Price;

ShopID  BrandID Brand_Name  Price
18         1    coke         41
 9         1    sprite       115
 1         1    fanta        141
```

as you can see it shows me all 3 values i know all the brands are one 1 even though they are separate brands but i essentially want to remove the middle one so it only shows me the minimum and maximum values, just not sure how to go about this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add data examples and expected result to make the question more clear

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use MAX and MIN functions, please refer to this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Also you can check these threads:

1. [SQL Functions using MIN and MAX together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783372/sql-functions-using-min-and-max-together)
2. [How to return MAX and MIN of a value from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206408/how-to-return-max-and-min-of-a-value-from-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

You should use MIN and MAX on column name.
eg-SELECT MIN(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE your_condition;

Or

eg-SELECT MAX(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE your_condition;

Also if you want to use them together
SELECT
MIN(column_name) AS min_col,
MAX(column_name) AS max_col
FROM table_name;